# Anomaly using natbib

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I am using the following command in a `.cls` file:

```
\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

for references.

I do not know why the output of the compilation shows an additional rectangle.

[image]

Further information:

in the `.cls` file I use:

```
\RequirePackage[unicode=true, pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
```

in the main file `main.tex` I use:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

Comment: A minimal example is necessary.

Comment: this is just a conjecture.  when references are compressed, there's no way to link the "missing" ones.  it's likely that the "extra" rectangle is the result of an effort to recognize that limitation.

Comment: I have just checked out all the references. There are no missing links.

Comment: I am utterly unable to reproduce the problem you report getting. Please, please tell us which document class you use, which bibliography style you employ, and which other citation-related packages (if any) you load.

Comment: Thanks for providing information on the bibliography style and the options passed to the `hyperref` package. There must be something more going in the the class file and/or in the preable of your document, as I continue to be unable to reproduce the problem you say you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem.
It seems that it was a conflict between `natbib` and `hypernat`.
I have just removed:

```
\usepackage{hypernat}
```

Comment: The `hypernat` package hasn't been updated since 2001. Moreover, its user manual states "This package will disappear from the CTAN, when `natbib` will do the job by [it]self." In short, it should *not* be used by anyone unless they must use a 14 year old TeX distribution...